# When I use this stored procedure in EF 5 it returns always 0

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, visual-studio-2012, sql-server-2012

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[ReadReviewCountByHotelId]
@HotelId uniqueidentifier
AS 
-- Returns the review count for given hotel.
BEGIN
    SELECT Count(r.ReviewId) as ReviewCount 
    FROM Review r 
    WHERE r.Review_HotelId = @HotelId
END;
```

When I use this stored procedure  in EF 5  it returns always 0.
I other procedures there is no problem.

```
public static int ReadReviewCountByHotelId(Guid? hotelId)
{
    int reviewCount = 0;
    try
    {
        var tEntities = new TravelEntities();
        Int32.TryParse(tEntities.ReadReviewCountByHotelId(hotelId).ToString(),out reviewCount);               
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception(ex.Message);
    }
    return reviewCount;
}
```

EF function as

```
public virtual ObjectResult<Nullable<int>> ReadReviewCountByHotelId(Nullable<System.Guid> hotelId)
{
    var hotelIdParameter = hotelId.HasValue ?
        new ObjectParameter("HotelId", hotelId) :
        new ObjectParameter("HotelId", typeof(System.Guid));

    return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<Nullable<int>>("ReadReviewCountByHotelId", hotelIdParameter);
}
```

I use EF in my project. I see this problem for the first time.

Thank you for your attention

Comment: So it is clear that no records exists for this condition `r.Review_HotelId = @HotelId` try giving a different `@HotelId` which is already present in `Review_HotelId` column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return value of TryParse is not being checked. If the following line is not able to parse the result, it returns false and does not alter the value of reviewCount which has been initialized to zero. It does not throw an exception.

```
Int32.TryParse(tEntities.ReadReviewCountByHotelId(hotelId).ToString(),out reviewCount);
```

The ToString() call on the results looks suspicious as the return value is an ObjectResult of T. That appears to be a wrapper for an enumerable/list implementation. Its is probably not returning a string representation of the scaler result set from the stored proc. I am thinking that that the line should look more like:

```
reviewCount = tEntities.ReadReviewCountByHotelId(hotelId).First().Value
```

Comment: Int32.TryParse(tEntities.ReadReviewCountByHotelId(hotelId).FirstOrDefault().ToString(),out reviewCount);

It worked after above modifications

Comment: But First or default should be returning a Nullible<int>. There should be no reason to convert it to a string and back to an int.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if you actually pass in a valid id. But try:

Set NoCount On

as the first line in your sproc? That could be a likely culprit.

And in general, make this a scalar function? More appropriate for what you're doing.